# Редактирование текста "на лету"

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать редактирование текста прямо на странице? Например, есть текст взятый из базы данных, нажимаешь кнопку редактировать текст сменяется на     `<textarea>этот же текст из базы</textarea>`. Пользователь вносит изменения нажимает на кнопку сохранить и текст обновляется. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где-то я уже это писал, ну да ладно.

```
<div id="pagecontent">text</div>
<div id="pagecontrols">
    <img src="img/i.gif" alt="" class="icon3edit pageedit" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pageedit').toggle(function(){
    var c = $('#pagecontent');
    c.html('<textarea id="pageeditor" cols="80" rows="10">'+c.html()+'</textarea>');
    $(this).toggleClass('icon3edit icon3ok');
}, function(){
    $.post(__ADRESS__, {'text': $('#pageeditor').val()}, function(data){
        $('#pagecontent').html(data);
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('icon3edit icon3ok');
});
</script>
```

Используется jQuery, сообщение шлется на `__ADRESS__`. Ну, и присутствует украшательство в виде иконки.

Comment: Содержимое #pageeditor записывается в бд, но пропуская момент редактирования. А если не указывать путь, то textarea появляется нормально. Как это исправить?

Comment: Возможно, ваш скрипт не обновляет текст в базе или же сбрасывает ваши изменения. Проверьте его.

Comment: В этой строчке не понятно, `"c.html('<textarea id="pageeditor" cols="80" rows="10">'+c.html()+'</textarea>');"` получается что `c.html()` уже содержит `"<textarea id="pageeditor" cols="80" rows="10"> текст в диве #pagecontent"`. Записывается вместе с открытым тегом `textarea`. А если поле вынести в отдельный див (не заменять `#pagecontent`), то проблема исчезает, но не срабатывает `.val()`. Уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: При клике по `.pageedit` срабатывает то одна, то другая функция. Первая закидывает innerHTML `#pagecontent` в textarea, а вторая - отправляет данные и меняет innerHTML на ответ сервера (по хорошему, это должен быть отправленный код). Если у вас код оборачивается дважды в textarea, значит, не получен ответ от сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

*гуглим инфу о **contentEditable***

Answer (score 0):

Как только текст изменили, пользователь применяет изменения нажатием кнопки, по нажатию заменяешь текст в бд(если вытащить смог то и запишешь ведь да), что бы все работало красиво хорошо бы использовать для этого ajax. Реализуй сначала так, потом читай про ajax.